# Does existence of primitive $n$-th root of unity imply $n$ is a unit?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, roots-of-unity, fast-fourier-transform

I am studying the fast Fourier transform algorithm in von zur Gathen and Gerard's *Modern computer algebra*. In it (p. 220), they seem to claim that in a ring with unity where we can apply the discrete Fourier transform, i.e; a ring with a primitive $n$-th root of unity, we also have an inverse. But this is only the case if the element $n$ in our ring is invertible for the multiplication.

Where they sloppy or is there some relation I have missed between the existence of some primitive $n$-th root of unity and the ring element $n=1+\ldots+1$?

Comment: I don't have the book but searching on Google Books, it seems that the authors have defined "primitive $n$-th root of unity" only for rings where $n$ is a unit.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I guess I missed this while reading the definition.